# Ignore subsequent goals in Makefile

Tags: makefile

I have a Makefile that allows me to check if a service is running:

```
make status [service]
```

E.G.

```
make status app
make status database
```

I would like to add another goal that allows me to check some application statistics:

```
make app status
```

However, after running the "app" goal, `make` tries to run the "status" goal. How can I tell make to exit after running a goal?

I have tried adding `exit` to the `app` goal, but this just stops the execution of `app` - make still proceeds to `status`.

Comment: That's not really how make is meant to be used. Each (non-option) argument is a target that it should achieve. So `make status app` and `make app status` by definition aim to produce the same targets. It sounds like you're trying to turn make into a general-purpose tool that it's not really meant to be. You could of course have targets like `status_app` and `app_status` and define them differently.

Comment: You could also use make variables instead of goals: `make status WHAT=app` or `make app STATISTICS=yes` and use these variables inside your `Makefile` to modify the default behavior. Conditionals like `ifeq ($(STATISTICS),yes) ... endif` are one of the many ways to do this.